# How do I recover files from U1 cloud

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync, mac, data-recovery

OK I have just stopped syncing a folder. This appears to have been a huge mistake. I did not realise the folder would disappear from my cloud storage. I assume (and hope) the sub-folders/files it contained still exists in the cloud. I hope they still exists in the cloud because they do not exist on my computer. I did not delete these files from the cloud (I have tried to recover deleted files - none are being recovered). Where are they and how do I get them back into My storage?

Comment: @DuminduMahawela If you "stop sync" from the Nautilus context menu, yes it does delete all the files from the server as well.

Comment: Ok. I messed up with disconnect option in Indicator-u1. Better you  did pointed-out. Otherwise I could have done some disastrous deed.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to stop synchronizing a folder. One is to stop synchronizing the folder *locally* while still keeping the “cloud” copy alive. This is done from the Ubuntu One Control Panel, by deselecting the per-volume checkbox that is labelled “Sync Locally?”,
[image: the Ubuntu One control panel’s “sync locally” checkbox]

With this option your files will remain on the cloud, and on any other devices where you have previously (or thereafter) selected that checkbox.

The other way (which was removed for new installations as of 13.10) is to remove the folder from Ubuntu One entirely. This is done from the Nautilus context menu,
[image: the Nautilus folder context menu’s “Stop synchronizing this folder” entry]

With this option the volume and its files are removed from the cloud, and will no longer be synced to other devices where they might have been synced before. They won't be removed from this or other devices, but you no longer have a way to retrieve them from the website. The “recover deleted files” does not recover deleted volumes.

The file blobs will be removed after the usual window, but you've lost the handle on them. At this point you're pretty much out of luck if you later remove the files and need them back.

> From the commandline, the control panel action corresponds to `u1sdtool --unsubscribe-folder`, whereas the nautilus action corresponds to `u1sdtool --delete-folder`.

Comment: The Nautilus context menu method is no longer in 13.10.

Comment: Also, I'm fairly sure using _Stop Synchronizing_ in the Nautilus menu will result in the files being deleted in the cloud, and moved to trash on other devices which were also synchronizing them.

Comment: dobey, I have it, and I'm in 13.10. hackers ppa?

Comment: It isn't removed on upgrades, but it's not included in 13.10. You probably still have the old package installed. No longer in the PPA either.

Comment: Gotcha. Edited to include the info.

Answer (score 0):

Please Login to the Ubuntu One Account with your web browser [with this link.](http://one.ubuntu.com)

Use your existing ubuntu one account name and password. When you got in to the main page, Click to the files link. At the next page, there should be a link saying, "Recover deleted files"

1. If your files are still there, you can download them.
2. If your files are not there, try "Recover deleted files" choice.

Good luck.

Comment: That won't work on deleted volumes...